# Simplify a short code

Tags: code-review

Is there a better way to write the following? I am trying to make my code as clean as possible.

```
FFFF = {w1, w2, w3, w4, d} \[Function] Module[{weights, solutions},

 weights = {w1, w2, w3, w4};
   solutions = {d/w1, d/w2, d/w3, d/w4, w1, w2, w3, w4};

   If[Mod[d, weights] == {0, 0, 0, 0} && d/w1 > 1 && 
     d/w2 > 1 && d/w3 > 1 && d/w4 > 1, 
    StringTemplate["w^``+y^``+x^``+z^``with weights: ``,``,``,``"]
                  [d/w1, d/w2, d/w3, d/w4, w1, w2, w3, w4], 
    "No Possible FFFF"]]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
ffff[wts_?VectorQ, d_Integer] := With[{soln = d/wts},
  If[AllTrue[wts, # < d &] && AllTrue[soln, IntegerQ],
    StringTemplate["w^``+y^``+x^``+z^`` with weights: ``,``,``,``"] @@ Join[soln, wts],
   "No Possible FFFF"]
]
```

This assumes that (as seems to be the case) you are working with positive integers.